# Inserting empty spaces instead of NULLs with BULK INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using BULK INSERT to insert multiple registers into a database, which already has data in it.
I was wondering if there's any way to insert empty spaces instead of NULLs, so the inserted data is visually consistent with the previous data.
This is the script I'm using.

```
BULK INSERT Documentos
FROM '\\Cate-des-tn-032\2015\InsertAWeb_07-05-2019.csv'
WITH (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

UPDATE Documentos
    SET FechaCargaLote = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 120)
    WHERE FechaCarga LIKE '%2015%'
```

Comment: What are you storing dates as a strings?  Something is wrong.

Comment: It was the format they had before I got here, all the apps are wokring that way. I don't really know why it was set that way.

Comment: Personally, I would change your existing data to use `NULL`, rather than `''`. `NULL` means a value is unknown, which clearly is what your `''` is representing, and (also) you can't store `''` in the `date` datatype; it'll be implicitly cast to `19000101`.

Comment: Since the date is stored as varchar, it allows NULL so I just insert it empry and update it afterwards

Comment: Also, since we have to constantly check the data, having `''` instead of `NULL` makes it easyer to read

Comment: `date` allows `NULL` as well; every native data type in SQL Server does. Personally, `WHERE MyDate = ''` makes little sense when compared to `WHERE MyDate IS NULL`. As, like I mentioned before, `WHERE MyDate = ''` translates to `WHERE MyDate = '19000101'` when using the correct data type.

Comment: I know this database is not optimal, but it is working, and the date is not currently my issue. I was just wondering if instead of `NULL` I can use `''` as default

Comment: Is modifying the csv an option?

Comment: @TEEKAY Yes, what would I need to put in the empty spaces?

Comment: You should never do a bulk insert to the destination table. You should use a staging table that would allow you to handle data properly. If something goes wrong during the import, you might be compromising all the data.

Comment: @LuisCazares noted, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a scenario for using a staging table.  First load all data as VarChar().  Then Insert Into your actual table with conversions as needed.

**Setup Tables:**

```
Create Table #staging_tbl
(
id VarChar(5),
dt VarChar(15)
)

Create Table #actual_tbl
(
id Int,
dt VarChar(10)
)
```

**Sample File [test.txt]**

```
1;2019-05-12
1;2019-05-11
1;2019-05-10
1;
1;2019-05-08
2;2019-04-19
```

**Bulk Insert**

```
BULK INSERT #staging_tbl
FROM 'c:\Downloads\test.txt' 
WITH 
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

**Move data from staging table to actual table: Convert NULL to 'blank'**

```
Insert Into #actual_tbl
SELECT 
  id,
  Case When dt Is Null Then '' Else dt End As d
FROM #staging_tbl
```

**Query actual table**

```
Select * From #actual_tbl
```

**Result:**

```
id  dt
1   2019-05-12
1   2019-05-11
1   2019-05-10
1   
1   2019-05-08
2   2019-04-19
```

Comment: Although you could use `COALESCE` to simplify a bit. Also, I think it would be better to use different attribute names in your staging vs main tables, to avoid confusions (and to explicitly list attribute names in the `INSERT` statement).